# Fade and Kenburns effect to same image

Tags: javascript, css

I need to put both the kenburn effect and the fade effect to same image, when I click a link.

I tried to do it my way, but it is not working perfectly.

I need to fade and kenburn the first image when I click `box1`, likewise with the second image.

I put JavaScript twice for both images. I need it put once for both image but need to  click both box1 and box2 for fade and kenburn each images.

Can you please help with this?

[This is my work. DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/akdNd/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box1').on('click', function () {
        $('#slideimg01').addClass('zoom'),2000;
    });
});

$(".box1").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    gogo();
});

var gogo = function(){


$("#slideimg1 img").clone().appendTo("#slideimg1").hide().css({ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 });
$("#slideimg1 img:first").fadeOut(1000,'linear');
$("#slideimg1 img:last").fadeIn(1000,'linear');

};
```

Comment: is it a social-type thing where the user selects the amount of fade and ken burns or is it just a styling feature with fixed fade and ken burns?

Comment: Your question is not very descriptive. But something wrong with your JS is you can't gradually add a class. So remove the `,2000` from the `addClass('zoom')` function

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to do apply that effect on each image by clicking on the respective box of it
you need to read about `$(this), eq(), index()`in http://api.jquery.com/
there's too many ways to do this and i think this is the efficient one :
1-get the index of the box
2-apply the effect on the image that has the same index

this is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akdNd/8/)

remember that you don't have to copy the same jquery code for each box, you can use `$(this)` in stead